# How can I search a MYSQL database varchar() table column for existence of ANY of list of "keyword" strings?

Tags: mysql, flask, full-text-search, forms, http-post

I'm building a CRUD application on the Python Flask framework with MYSQL backend and HTML5 front end. I need to parse search text entered by the user into the HTML form text input element and subsequently POST'ed to the server upon clicking the HTML submit input element ("button"). I would like to query the MYSQL database off a python list of string "keywords" derived from splitting the text retrieved from the form **POST** using the .split() method in python; a list of string "keywords" will result. I know you can search for instances of a single string literal using the **LIKE** keyword with the (**~%** OR **~__**) functionalities in SQL but I don't think SQL implementations have anything like a list of elements like Python supports.

To summarize, I need to form a dynamic SQL query based on a list of python strings that depends on what a user inputs to an HTML form text input. The list will vary in size --but not be huge -- based on the whims of user input.

I intend to split on white-space a single POST string coming from an HTML form POST space into a list of strings using the SomeString.split() method in Python. and construct a query from that list. Its a bit confusing to me how to do this for a list of arbitrary size. I understand there is a Full-text search feature in MYSQL based on indexing but that exists on the Database side while the list exist on the Python server side.

```py
...
...
def parser(PostedString):
    lastword = PostedString[-1]
    keywords = PostedString.split()
    sqlquery = """SELECT *
                  FROM vehicle
                  WHERE VehicleDescr LIKE %"""
    for word in keyword[:-1}:
        sqlquery = sqlquery + word + "% OR LIKE"
    sqlquery = sqlquery + "%" + lastword + "%"
    return sqlquery
...
...
cursor.exectute(sqlquery)
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

I hope to get a subset of the rows in the table. I worry that this method will not be efficient for large datasets in a database. I would like implement the fastest, most comprehensive solution but I am not super advanced in python, flask, or SQL. Thank You

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best way to compose the query. Normally you want to be super careful about avoiding data in your query and use placeholders like `%s` to represent them instead.

Comment: Consider using a [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) statement to join your individual query results